# Why my function doesn't work after wrapped lodash.debounce?

Tags: angular, lodash, debouncing

I wrote a function that fires on some events and calls the service. Without a debounce, everything works correctly, but the server will crash on too chatty events. I tried wrapping the function in a debounce, but it stopped working. What could be the problem?

```
 resethUserState() {
    this.authService.sessionExtention().subscribe();
    console.log('reset');
  }

  @HostListener('window:click')
  @HostListener('window:mousemove')
  @HostListener('window:keydown')
  function() {
    debounce(this.resethUserState, 1000);
  }
```

How can I fix this behavior?

**EDITED**

The full component

```
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import Paths from '../../paths';
import { PushNotificationService } from 'src/app/push-notification.service';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lobby',
  templateUrl: './lobby.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lobby.component.scss'],
})
export class LobbyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,

    private pushNotificationService: PushNotificationService
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  logoutUser() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.pushNotificationService.createNotification('Logged out!');
    this.router.navigate([`/${Paths.Login}`]);
    return false;
  }


   resetUserState() {
     this.authService.sessionExtention().subscribe();
     console.log('reset');
   }
   
  @HostListener('window:click')
  @HostListener('window:mousemove')
  @HostListener('window:keydown')
   function() {
     debounce(this.resetUserState, 1000);
   }
 
}
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of your component?

Comment: @MathewBerg, yeah sure, I just attached it.

Answer (score 0):

As for me this solution works:

```
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import Paths from '../../paths';
import { PushNotificationService } from 'src/app/push-notification.service';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lobby',
  templateUrl: './lobby.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lobby.component.scss'],
})
export class LobbyComponent implements OnInit {
  DEBOUNCE_TIME = 300000;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,

    private pushNotificationService: PushNotificationService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  logoutUser() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.pushNotificationService.createNotification('Logged out!');
    this.router.navigate([`/${Paths.Login}`]);
    return false;
  }

  resetUserState = debounce(() => {
    this.authService.sessionExtention().subscribe();
  }, this.DEBOUNCE_TIME);

  @HostListener('window:click')
  @HostListener('window:mousemove')
  @HostListener('window:keydown')
  function() {
    this.resetUserState();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's the same as you write `this.resetUserState`, you just declare the function, you need to invoke the function to make it work - `debounce(this.resetUserState, 1000)()`